# Align image with the last line of a header sentence

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a header element that I have set to a max width, which causes it to span multiple lines. I would like an image to be placed next to the last sentence.

You can see what I have accomplished so far here:

https://codepen.io/Csaborio/pen/JjmGxom

```css
.container {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: end;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 15ch;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /* Uncomment below to see where I want the image */
/*     margin-left: -270px; */
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Your baby’s movements matter</h1>
  <img src="https://phx02pap004files.storage.live.com/y4mEatNiAqNzspboF8a53zumO1Zjc6AEFSz3_yWhBllkJcfyl4ABajY3IQoHHUdXGWh0jFPdczZT1Grc29XRyxzJWa4DK9OYMt8fBhtcwunjz_TwklpxzODmu0sYrFSOH4WTO52Z5B_4dO_8-PepQJkwNguz4ORxqUyx8mxEhhz0I05_KYdKRQRUUEiEE68ZVAu?encodeFailures=1&width=100&height=100" />
</div>
```

What I would like is to have the image next to the last sentence:

[image: Desired Outcome]

which can be achieved with negative margins, but that would break apart if the max-width of the header changes when hitting different breakpoints.

I am looking for something that would cause that image element to be next to the last sentence of the header regardless of width of the header element.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: just insert your img inside of your h1

Comment: Good god, talk about overthinking things, thanks for that! :-)

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 2):

is it you want?

```css
.container {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: end;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 15ch;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;    
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Your baby’s movements matter
  <img src="https://phx02pap004files.storage.live.com/y4mEatNiAqNzspboF8a53zumO1Zjc6AEFSz3_yWhBllkJcfyl4ABajY3IQoHHUdXGWh0jFPdczZT1Grc29XRyxzJWa4DK9OYMt8fBhtcwunjz_TwklpxzODmu0sYrFSOH4WTO52Z5B_4dO_8-PepQJkwNguz4ORxqUyx8mxEhhz0I05_KYdKRQRUUEiEE68ZVAu?encodeFailures=1&width=100&height=100" />
  </h1>  
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I had no idea that you were allowed to insert things within h tags, thanks!